# ANT-APACHE: During the CONCAT operation the terminating line of each File(which is blank) is being removed?

Tags: xml, ant, concatenation

**Here is the Build.xml file which i have used to build the CONCAT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<property file="******************"/>

<taskdef name="jscomp" classname="com.google.javascript.jscomp.ant.CompileTask" classpath="${closure.path}"/>

<target name="concatenate">
    <concat destfile="${concat.output}" fixlastline="yes">
        <filelist dir="${sources.dir}" files="${sources.files}" />
    </concat>
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="concatenate">
    <jscomp compilationLevel="${jscomp.compilation_level}" warning="${jscomp.warning}" debug="${jscomp.debug}" output="${jscomp.output}">
        <sources dir="${sources.dir}" files="${sources.files}" />
    </jscomp>
</target>
```

**Dummy file 1**

```
console.log('First File');
```

**Dummy File 2**

```
console.log('Second File');
```

**Expected Output**

```
console.log('First File');

console.log('Second File');
```

**Actual Output**

```
console.log('First File');
console.log('Second File');
```

Comment: Hi Nipun.  I'm guessing a bit, but I can't recreate the issue you mention.  Try and make a small build file that just runs a concat with a couple of text files and see if you can narrow it down.  If you can't figure out the issue using that method, you can post the whole build here, with your test files so other people can try and help.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the reply! I tried it with two small dummy files, still I am facing the same issue. I am using it for JavaScript files using VS Code IDE on macOS Big Sur 11.2.3. And i am building it using the ant -f  command

Comment: If you can post the build file and the dummy files, what you see output, what you expect output, we can try and help.  Ant version might be a factor too (ant -version).

Comment: Updated the Question. I am using Ant 1.10.9.

Comment: I know it won't help much, but it works ok for me, ant 1.10.9, macOS 10.15.7.  I get a four-line file, with two blank lines.  My build is just a concat task, no jscomp, no taskdef for jscomp.

Comment: Could you please send me the build file?